# Modify Javascript to search from multiple columns

Tags: javascript, html

im using this javascript code to search a column with input that I write to my search input field. After I type to input field, table only shows rows from that one column.

```js
function search()
{
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, textValue;

    input = document.getElementById("myInput");

    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();

    table = document.getElementById("myTable");

    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    for (i=0; i < tr.length; i++)
    {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
        if(td)
        {
            textValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;

            if(textValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter)> -1)
            {
                tr[i].style.display=""
            }
            else
            {
                tr[i].style.display="none";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The column is picked on this line by [1].

My question is how do I change my javascript code to select multiple columns that I want to search from?

```js
td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
```

There is my HTML search input

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="offset-md-3 col-md-6">
            <input type="text" id="myInput" class="form-control" placeholder="Live Searching..." onkeyup="search();">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

There is also my HTML table with som PHP in it

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" style="margin-top: 50px;" id="myTable"> 
<tr> 
<?php 
$select="select * from videos"; 
$result=mysqli_query($con,$select); 
?>  
      <thead class="sortable">
        <tr> 
           <th> Video </th>
              <th> Názov </th>
           <th> Autor </th>
           <th> Tagy </th>
           <th> Žáner </th>
           <th> Hodnotenie </th>
              <th> Rozlíšenie videa </th> 
              <th> Počet Snímkov </th> 
           <th> Dĺžka videa</th>
              <th> Dátum Vytvorenia </th> 
           <th> Úprava </th>
        </tr> 
      </thead>

        <?php while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
        { 
         $location = $rows['location'];
        ?> 
      <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td><?php echo "<video src='".$location."' controls width='200px' height='200px' ></video>"; ?></td>  
         <td><?php echo $rows['FileName']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $rows['author']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $rows['tags']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $rows['genre']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $rows['rating']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $rows['ImageSize']; ?></td> 
           <td><?php echo $rows['VideoFrameRate']; ?></td> 
         <td><?php echo $rows['MediaDuration']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $rows['CreateDate']; ?></td> 
         <td><a href=""><i class="bi bi-pencil-square" style="font-size: 30px;"></i></a></td>
         
        </tr>
      </tbody> 
       <?php 
          } 
      ?> 
    </table>
```

Comment: Using *php* filter function is better than *javascript* since you are using data get from php.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to iterate over all `td`-elements of each table row in your `search()` function.

I would also recommend using [String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) for finding a valid match.

The following code should work:

```
function search()
{
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, textValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    // iterating over all rows of the table
    for (i=0; i < tr.length; i++)
    {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
        // flag which indicates if there was a match in the current row
        let found = false;

        // iterating over all td elements of each row
        for (j=0; j < td.length; j++)
        {
            textValue = td[j].textContent || td[j].innerText;
            textValue = textValue.toUpperCase();
            if ( textValue.includes(filter) === true)
            {
                // we found a match
                found = true;
            }
        }

        // show or hide current row
        if (found === false)
        {
                tr[i].style.display="none";
        } else {
                tr[i].style.display=""
        }
    }
}
```

---

You also have an error in your html/php. The `<tbody>` tag should not be within the while loop.

---

Also you might be interested in the javascript library [DataTables](https://datatables.net/).